# VS2008 C++ project - Step into 3rd party code in release mode

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am working on a VS2008 unmanaged C++ project that uses an in house build of OpenCV 2.4.12.  I would like to be able to step into the OpenCV code, but I am not sure how to get that to happen.  I believe that if I add the OpenCV build project into my VS2008 solution, I should be able to step into the OpenCV code without a problem.  That is doable, but is it necessary to have the 3rd party projects inside my solution?  Is there instead, a way to point at the source files in order for VS2008 to find them and allow for stepping in.  This is not something I have done in this version of the IDE.

I particularly want to be able to step in when running in release mode, as the issue I am trying to track down only happens in release.  I have rebuilt the OpenCV code release binaries with debug information turned on, along with all other options that are necessary to support running with debug information.  Now I just need to be able to actually step into the source files as I am running.

I have seen some others asking about stepping into files and have not seen anything that helps my situation.  Particularly since I am working with unmanaged C++ and I'm trying to debug in release mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've had good luck tracking down bugs in release mode by adding a global, `static volatile int track;`. then peppering code at the suspicious places with `track++;` to get around the reordering issues Release optimization does. Also try opening the asym view window just before calling a OpenCV function then you can step into anything.

Comment: If the debug info is available you should be able to step into the functions. You have to add debug info to both the compiler and linker step (which are two different project options). The debugger should then find the debug info. If it isn't, make sure that your built DLLs are loading and not ones that are located elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I've added debug info to both.  Ok, let me take a look and see if there's something I missed.  Are you saying that it should be able to step into a c++ file, not just the header?  I know on Linux it just does that.
As to "suspicious" places, I am at a loss because the program crashes at a call to cv::transpose() that our code never directly makes.  Also, the call stack shows cv::transpose() at the bottom, with no information as to how it got called, and no reference at all to our code.  I was thinking I could just put a breakpoint in transpose() and at least see how it is called.

Comment: @doug - Sorry, Just reread your comment. I'm not sure I know what the asym view window is. Is it something that I instantiate in my code?

Comment: So I just tried stepping into OpenCV calls in release and the debugger just stepped right over the calls.  My current line was pointing to the "copyTo(m);" line in Mat::clone() (mat.hpp).  It seems I can only get into the header files.